# Regex for a value in URL - Screen scraping

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, preg-match, screen-scraping

I've tried a number of various instances and I just can't seem to get it right, so reaching out in hopes others can assist with this project.

Working on a PHP based scrape project.

I am wanting to grab the "5094151" from the url below:

http://www.test.com/item/11-x-17-1-1-2-Gold-Distressed-Picture-Frame-11101202-5094151

Keep in mind that this number "5094151" represents an item number, for an item listing, so each URL will be different and the numbers can vary in size. For example, the length of this number could be 4 digits, it could be 7, it could be 10.

I am looking for a preg_match function which can give me this number.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I probably should clarify a little more ... Im using a php based scrape function which "spools" up the urls from the page ... The prior method was: [code]preg_match_all('~"(http://www.test.com/item/[^"]+)"~is', $index, $matches); [/code] that no longer works of course, since the markup changed to look like the url as giving initially, so am looking for the correct method to update this particular one.

Comment: are you saying that you want to get all *"item numbers"* from the url and not just the last one?

Comment: What we're doing, is loading page, checking  if any links exist, and if so, load them up and scrape the data that we need from them. Example:<br><br>$url = ((int) $page == $page) ? $base_url.'?page=profile&pg='.$page.'&profile_username='.$username : $page;
                $index = $curl->fetch_url($url, $post, $cur_ip);
                //detail urls and categories
                preg_match_all('~"(http://www.test.com/item/[^"]+)"~is', $index, $matches);
                foreach($matches[1] as $key => $value)
                {
                        $ret[$value] = $value;
                }

Comment: Please update your question, hard to read code as comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+$
```

- `\d+` matches as many digits as possible (minimum of one)
- `$` matches the end of the string

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/vB2zM4/1)

```
preg_match('/\d+$/', $url, $item_number);
echo $item_number[0]; // => 5094151
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your current example this regex should find the `id`.

```
.*-(\d+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oD5eV8/1

The `.*` says capture every/any character until the last `-`. The `\d` is a number the `+` is one or more numbers and the `()` captures the value.

Usage in PHP,

```
$string = 'http://www.test.com/item/11-x-17-1-1-2-Gold-Distressed-Picture-Frame-11101202-5094151http://www.test.com/item/11-x-17-1-1-2-Gold-Distressed-Picture-Frame-11101202-5094151';
preg_match('~.*-(\d+)~', $string, $id);
echo $id[1];
```

Output:

> 5094151

The `~`s in the PHP example are delimiters; they distinguish where the regex starts and ends.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the last part of the string and it always ends with `-{number}`, there's no need for regex:

```
$num = strrchr($url, '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex also you can get that id by exploding URL string.

```
$string = 'http://www.test.com/item/11-x-17-1-1-2-Gold-Distressed-Picture-Frame-11101202-5094151';
$id = end(explode("-",$string));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = preg_replace('/.*-/', '', $url);
```

That way you can keep it on one line.